# Can a power with "target: one creature" be used on an empty square in an attempt to hit a hidden creature?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, stealth, attack

Say that I'm in the midst of a battle, and I know that there's an Invisible and Hidden creature somewhere. Am I allowed to use a power that says "Target: One creature" on a random square in an attempt to hit the hidden creature? Is it enough for me to have a target in mind, or does the location need to be explicitly known first?

The Rules Compendium (p221) seems to imply that you can just pick a square and guess, but I'm not sure if that applies to all attacks or just powers that use blast/burst.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**

Unfortunately I don't have access to the Rules Compendium but in the core, it says in a sidebar:

> Pick a Square and Attack: Choose a square to attack, using whatever information you’ve gleaned so far about the target’s location. Roll the attack normally (taking the –5
>   penalty for attacking a creature that has total concealment). If you pick the wrong square, your attack automatically misses, but only the DM knows whether you guessed the wrong square or your attack just missed.

Now, where this gets hazy is if this is just a way to launch after effects.  I don't believe there's a rule saying you can't, but it's the miss effects that really make this questionable.  But ultimately that's up to your DM.

Comment: That's pretty much the same as what it says in the Rules Compendium; I have a feel it doesn't get more specific then that (unless I've missed some errata somewhere).

I hadn't considered miss effects; generally when going creature hunting I'll only be using at-will powers though so I don't think it'll come up too much in practice.